# Fibonacci Sequence printing out all values in an array EDIT

Tags: java, class, methods, fibonacci, runner

Okay my new question is how I can let the array print out all numbers of the segment. At the moment I can input a number and the code will print out the corresponding value in Fibonacci. However, I would like the array to print out all values leading up to the answer. Ex. Input = 7,  array prints out 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 instead of just 8

```
package math;
public class Fibonacci {
    public static long getFib(int n) {
        long Fibby[] = new long[n+1];
        Fibby[0] = 1;
        Fibby[1] = 1;       
    for(int i = 2; i<=n; i++) {    //initialize loop        
        Fibby[i] = Fibby[i-1] + Fibby[i-2];             
    } // end of for loop
    return Fibby[n];   //end method getfib    
    }
}
```

And the runner

```
package math;


         Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);



        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci();
        int p;
        System.out.println("Fib value : ");
        p = key.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "Fib Value of "+ p +" :: " + f.getFib(p) );



    }
```

How can this happen? My question has been downsized.

Comment: What is `package math` supposed to do? All the code you're showing is base java. Also, what are `radius` and `height`? (your code doesn't use them, Fibbonacci numbers certainly don't use them, why are they in the method signature and call?)

Comment: What do you mean runner? Runnable?

Comment: from the code, it looks like they mean "main class that becomes the executable"

Comment: "_I have complete errors_" If you have errors you should post them here.

Comment: Oh ok. Runner = Main Class

Comment: "Where you would put an input and the program would put the output of the place of that sequence part. " In main method `public static void main( String[] args )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run your main method, because `System.out.println()` expects a parameter it can print. However, your `fib()` method returns void, so there is nothing to print. Add a return type to your `fib()` method, and your error in `main()` will be resolved. Here's a demonstration of printing the 0th to 12th Fibonacci numbers:

> FibonacciRunner.java

```
public class FibonacciRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Fibonacci.fib(i));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Fibonacci.fibList(i));
        }
    }
}
```

> Fibonacci.java

```
public class Fibonacci
{
    public static long fib(int n)
    {
        long current = 0;
        long next = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            current += next;
            next += current;
        }
        return n % 2 == 0 ? current : next;
    }
    public static List<Long> fibList(int n)
    {
        List<Long> ret = new ArrayList<>(n == 0 ? List.of(0L) : List.of(0L, 1L));
        long current = 0;
        long next = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
        {
            current += next;
            next += current;
            if(i*2+1 <= n)
                ret.add(current);
            if(i*2+2 < n)
                ret.add(next);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that `Fibonacci.fib` doesn't return anything, so what are you expecting the `FibonacciRunner` to print?

Another is that arrays in Java have fixed length.  Consider using a `List` instead:

```
List fibby = new ArrayList();
fibby.add(0);
fibby.add(1);
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
   fibby.add(fibby.get(i - 1) + fibby.get(i - 2));
}
```

Comment: Making a list is a spectacularly bad idea for calculating the nth Fibonacci number, and a great idea for calculating the 1-to-nth Fibonacci numbers. As it is now, it appears that he wants "the output of the place of that sequence part", which probably indicates the nth Fibonacci number. They only need two variables to calculate the nth Fibonacci number, not a List.